# How to enable the touchpad on a Compaq Presario?

Tags: touchpad, compaq-laptop

I accidentally disabled the touchpad on a laptop (Presario CQ62 running Windows. I think I must have hit some shortcut key. How can I enable it again?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: And which model Presario?

Comment: By hitting the same shortcut key again? There are not that many `Fn` + `F*` keys. Some laptops have a dedicated hardware toggle button near the touchpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your model and operating system. Here are three possible solutions:

1. (**For Windows**) Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Mouse -> TouchPad On/Off
2. (**For any OS**) Look just above your touchpad for a button, probably with an amber or blue light. If it's not there, look along the top of your function keys for an icon that looks like your touchpad.
3. (**For Windows**) Go to Start, right click My Computer. Go to properties. Click on the hardware tab and go into it.
   Click on Device Manager. Look for your touch pad. Right click it and go to properties. You should have an option there to enable it.

Comment: There is a light *on* the touchpad, but no button there!

Answer (score 4):

A double tap within one second (like a double click) on the LED will turn the mouse pad on and off!

Answer (score 1):

I know on some Compaq Presarios there is a button at the top of the touchpad that will disable it. Check to see if there is a button for that above the touchpad. It could also be built into the touchpad itself, if this were the case you would see a light in one of the corners of the touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little button over the keypad with either a red light on or a white one on. if it's red then the keypad is disabled.

To reactivate it you need to press the button until it turns white.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, and I had to go to the driver recovery (on the hard drive) and re-install the drivers.  The prompt showed that the drivers were installed correctly, but the touchpad still didn't function.

So, I powered down the computer and REMOVED THE BATTERY for a couple minutes.

I re-installed the battery, booted it up and the computer is back to 100%

Answer (score 1):

I had to open device manager; computer management and uninstall the Synaptics PS/2 Port TouchPad driver. I reinstalled the driver from the following site. http://drivers.synaptics.com/Synaptics_v15_2_20_C_XP32_Vista32_Win7-32_Signed_Marketing_SGS94_UI-Scrybe.exe

Answer (score 1):

My gf has a Compaq CQ42 and after much consternation, we discovered that you tap the light in the corner of the touchpad three times, it re-enables the touchpad. Really stupid ui design there.

Answer (score 1):

The best process at any time in case of any malfunction, just shutdown the system for some time let the battery cool down and then restart the computer. 99% this will work out.

Answer (score 0):

Where you see the light on the side of the touch pad double tap that to enable. The light turns on when the pad is disabled and off when is enabled.

PS. The small light in on the upper left hand side of the pad you wanna double tap on the light itself. There is no button there.

Note: If your touch pad has a "dip" in the upper left corner, double tap that to enable/disable the touch pad.

Comment: Seems a bit harsh to me to vote down what seems like a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Compaq Presario CQ62 and your mouse pad is locked, at the top of the keyboard there is a lock picture. Just click that, and it will remove the red light.

Answer (score 0):

I have a compaq Presario 57 and have done this repeatedly all you do is double tap the dip in the upper left corner of the pad itself not the light, this will turn it off and since it is disabled it wont turn it back on.  you hold the alt key down and double tap it will turn back on instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control panel, mouse, and you should have a submenu called Device Settings (win8). Press Reset Devices, wait and that's all!

Answer (score -1):

Go to device manager, then Uninstall the driver but don't delete the driver.

Then I restart and install the driver again. after it reinstalls VIOLA. It works.